# neo4j cypher return structured map

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher

Lets say, we have a database with
 (:TvShow)-[:contain]->(:Season)-[:contain]->(:Episode)

Now lets say, one wants to query the database for a specific :TvShow and get a result shaped this way : 
{tvshow : //The tvShow node// , seasons: [ {season: //Season node// , episodes: [//episode node//]}]}

For exemple: if we have 
OneShow with 2 seasons and 3episodes

the result would be a json object:
{tvshow: OneShow, seasons: [{season: Season1, [episode1-1,episode1-2,episode1-3]},{season: Season1, [episode2-1,episode2-2,episode2-3]}]}

I'm trying to work with WITH, collect, FOREACH and the array operator '+' but without success yet.

Anyone has done this before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the following Neo4j console dataset http://console.neo4j.org/r/7uru0d, you can achieve it in this way :

```
MATCH (n:TvShow)-[:HAS_SEASON]->(season)-[:HAS_EPISODE]->(episode)
WITH n, season, collect(episode) AS ep
RETURN { show: n.id, seasons:collect({ season: season.name, episodes: ep })} AS shows
```

Comment: Your cypher is working perfectly, thanks. Except that in my app (not in your exemple) the arrarys are returned as objects : for exemple  [valeur1,valeur2] is returned {'0':valeur1,'1':valeur2}. Have you ever seen this behavior? It might be from Seraph the node.js module I use to communicate with Neo4j.

Comment: Well collections are ordered by keys, maybe you can post your js code in your question

Comment: Nevermind my comment, I have confirmed that the issue with the array formating comes from Seraph issue#147. Thank you Christophe